# how is flaxseed processed for consumption

Tags: flax

What part of flaxseed plant is actually consumed? What processes are done after harvest? Just want to know what we eat and how it is procured.

Answer (score 1):

Seeds are inside the dried fruit capsule. There is a wikipedia acticle on flax which covers [harvesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flax#Harvesting) and [processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flax#Processing).

Seed capsules are harvested by cutting and thrashing and broken to release the seeds, not really any processing other than cleaning and separation.

Another [link](http://www.motherearthliving.com/Gardening/Flax-Growing-and-Processing).